# Address validation service for a public website

Tags: api

Given the following scenario:

- There is a public website (with about 50-100 visitors a day)
- Visitors register for the services offered by the company who owns the website
- Visitors tend to give wrong information regarding address and phone number that slows down the process of their registration, therefore their transactions and general happiness about the services of the company
- Generaly the address validation adds value to the website

I am looking for a service for a reasonable price, that has:

- Up to date postcode and address database
- Easy to integrate API
- Address validation check
- All this with a reasonable price

I am looking specifically looking in the UK.

What I have found so far are companies having these services for on ridiculously  high price. We are also considering buying the PAF database from RoyalMail and implement such a service for ourselves.

Any help, suggestion is very much appreciated and thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Have previously used QAS (http://www.qas.co.uk), was pretty good but no idea how much it costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for a company called [Postcode Anywhere](http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/), we're an "information-as-a-service" provider that offers a [UK Address Finder](http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/uk-address-finder/).

We offer Royal Mail Postcode Address File (PAF) licensing on a per lookup basis, which will be much more cost effective for the volumes you're talking about. We have an API as well as ready-to-implement Javascript forms, for easy integration. We also provide a web service, so our data is also updated daily from the Royal Mail.

We have plenty of testamonials from major clients available, as well.

Comment: Tried to make this less spammy. It's a great answer with full disclosure of the answerer's relationship to the company, but I wasn't a fan of the marketing speak and excessive adjectives like "great".

Comment: After a bit more investigation, finally I integrated the website using Postcode Anywhere and I am 100% happy with their service level quality.